# Mouse movement doesn't appear to be updating fragment shader

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, fragment-shader

I'm trying to implement the Voronoi shader in the [Book of Shaders](https://thebookofshaders.com/12/) in three.js and cannot seem to wrap my head around why the mouse position is not having any effect on my visible output.  (This is for the initial demo where the mouse moves and the Voronoi updates)

I'm logging the mouse position, checking that the uniform value is updating, yet the shader doesn't appear to be changing whatsoever on my end.

This is what I see (static image - no change at all) while `animate` is being called.

[image: static voronoi]

I'm seeing `u_time` update when I log it in `animate` so the callback is happening.  The uniforms just don't appear to be updated and I *thought* I was updating them correctly.

Note - I followed this [SO post regarding tracking mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55850554/how-can-i-pass-the-mouse-positions-from-js-to-shader-through-a-uniform) as a basis, though I tried both that mouse position and the tweaked mouse I have below (to map from [-1,1]).

Full code:

```
<!--
  * Based on Book of Shaders 12:
  https://thebookofshaders.com/12/
-->

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>WebGL Demo - Voronoi</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="./libraries/threejs/three.min.js"></script>

  <!-- shaders -->
  <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
    void main() {
      vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition;
    }
  </script>
  <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">
    uniform vec2 u_resolution;
    uniform vec2 u_mouse;
    uniform float u_time;

    void main() {
      vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
      st.x *= u_resolution.x/u_resolution.y;

      vec3 color = vec3(.0);

      // Cell positions
      vec2 point[5];
      point[0] = vec2(0.83,0.75);
      point[1] = vec2(0.60,0.07);
      point[2] = vec2(0.28,0.64);
      point[3] = vec2(0.31,0.26);
      point[4] = u_mouse/u_resolution;

      float m_dist = 1.;  // minimum distance

      // Iterate through the points positions
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          float dist = distance(st, point[i]);

          // Keep the closer distance
          m_dist = min(m_dist, dist);
      }

      // Draw the min distance (distance field)
      color += m_dist;

      // Show isolines
      // color -= step(.7,abs(sin(50.0*m_dist)))*.3;

      gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body></body>

<script>
  let camera, scene, renderer;
  let uniforms, mesh;

  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.Camera();
    camera.position.z = 1;

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    uniforms = {
      u_resolution: { type: 'vec2', value: new THREE.Vector2() },
      u_mouse: { type: 'vec2', value: new THREE.Vector2() },
      u_time: { type: 'float', value: 1.0 }
    };

    let vShader = document.getElementById("vertexShader").textContent;
    let fShader = document.getElementById("fragmentShader").textContent;

    let geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2);

    // give it a material
    let material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: uniforms,
      fragmentShader: fShader,
      vertexShader: vShader,
    });

    // and now create the mesh (geom+mat)
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    onWindowResize();
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    uniforms.u_time.value += 0.05;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

  function onWindowResize(e) {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    uniforms.u_resolution.value.x = renderer.domElement.width;
    uniforms.u_resolution.value.y = renderer.domElement.height;
  }

  document.onmousemove = function (e) {
    uniforms.u_mouse.value.x = (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;//e.pageX / window.innerWidth;
    uniforms.u_mouse.value.y = -(e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;//e.pageY / window.innerHeight;
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `point[4] = u_mouse/u_resolution;` probably doesn’t need to be divided by `u_resolution` because the Vector2 is already in the `[-1, 1]` range. You might just be getting very small values so the mouse movement is indistinguishable.

Comment: Oh my, that was exactly it, thank you!  One minor point that I'm not clear on.  It now moves correctly by just removing the divide by `u_resolution`, however the mouse is offset by a positive x-value (about 1/2 of my screen to the right).  Is it possible I'm misinterpreting how three interacts with the mouse?  For reference, the diagram moves on the left of my screen while my mouse moves around on the right.

Comment: You commented out the `e.pageX / window.innerWidth;` method, but that’s probably the one you want because that would give you the `[0, 1]` range you need.

Comment: Interestingly, that makes it worse (y-movement is flipped and way off).  Changing to this helps but isn't quite mouse-perfect.  Is there something with the camera offset that maybe I'm missing?

`uniforms.u_mouse.value.x = (e.offsetX / window.innerWidth)*2;`
`uniforms.u_mouse.value.y = -(e.offsetY / window.innerHeight)*2+1;`

Comment: I’d need to see a working demo to get the exact formula to match the mouse position. But that’s probably a different question altogether.

Comment: I will add the question then, thanks :)

Comment: The followup is live, thanks for all your help so far!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73054651/mouse-offset-in-threejs-fragment-shader